# why C++ uses DOT to access structure members and -> to access method?

Tags: c++

I come from a Delphi/Pascal programming world but I also "play" around with C++ or C once in a while, there is a question that bothers me the most: why does C++ use "." to access a structure member and  "->" to access method? in Delphi/Pascal we use "." for any of those even properties...

Someone told me it has something to do with how C++ accesses memory, however that answer is NOT enough to help me understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All structure members (fields and methods) are accessed same way. But, in case of pointer to structure, there is two different syntaxes for the same purpose: (*pStruct).member and pStruct->member.

In Pascal (or Delphi):

```
var pointerToSomeRecord: ^SomeRecord;

pointerToSomeRecord^.field := 42;
```

In C++:

```
SomeStruct* pointerToSomeStruct;

(*pointerToSomeStruct).field = 42;
```

But, in C++ there is also another way:

```
pointerToSomeStruct->field = 42;
```

Most C++ programmers like the later form much more.

Answer (score 9):

Your understanding is incorrect. C++ accesses data members and member functions (the term "method" is not used by C++ programmers) the same way.

`.` accesses a member of an object. `->` accesses a member of the object that is pointed to by a pointer-to-object. `foo->bar` is exactly equivalent to `(*foo).bar`.

That is why someone told you "it has something to do with how C++ accesses memory" - because it does.

Comment: It's not *exactly* equivalent, because `foo->bar` actually means `foo {->operator->()} ->bar`, where `{exp}` means "repeat `exp` any number of times" :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: yes, I skipped over that, for hopefully obvious reasons. :) I was careless in my phrasing, though. +1.

Comment: @Fred: that should be `{.operator->()}`

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing them.

`foo->bar()` is semantically equivalent to `(*foo).bar()` (barring operator overload.)

`->` is used when the left-hand argument is a **pointer**.

`.` is used when it is a reference or otherwise not a pointer.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the right-hand side.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken.  C++ uses dot for member access and to call methods unless you have a pointer to the object the the -> operator applies.

The `->` is functionally the same as `(*obj).x()`

Answer (score 2):

The arrow operator is an abbreviation for accessing structure members via pointer:

```
struct foo {
   int field;
}

struct foo* ptr = ...;
```

This

```
(*ptr).field
```

is essentially the same as

```
ptr->field
```

This has nothting to do with accessing member functions or data fields.